# Python Proxy Firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

I am trying to make a "proxy" in Python that allows the user to route all of their web traffic through a host machine (this is mainly for me and a couple people I know to confuse/avoid hackers and/or spies, who would only see web pages and so on coming in through one IP). I have run into several difficulties. The first is that I would like to be able to use the final, compiled product with Firefox, which can be set to route all of its traffic through an installed proxy program. I don't know what kind of configuration my proxy needs to have to do this. Second, the way the proxy works is by using `urllib.requests.urlretrieve` (yes, going to die soon, but I like it) to download a webpage onto the host computer (it's inefficient and slow, but it's only going to be used for a max of 7-10 clients) and then sending the file to the client. However, this results in things like missing pictures or broken submission forms. What should I be using to get the webpages right (I want things like SSL and video streaming to work as well as pictures and whatnot).

Comment: "confuse/avoid hackers and/or spies" - I doubt it's going to help much. You're going to leak all kinds of identifying data and probably have a ton of vulnerabilities. This stuff is hard. What's wrong with using an existing proxy program?

Comment: @user2357112 I just like to know exactly what the program I'm running does, especially when it could easily track me or attempt a phishing attack.

Comment: @user2357112 As another point, most hackers and/or spies aren't targeting me, so if they see something that confuses them in the airport coffee shop, they are much more likely to look for another victim than start writing their own custom exploits to steal MY data. Also, sending all your requests to an IP you already know and letting that IP get what you want effectively foils MITM/DNS poisoning, assuming I set up a public-key cryptography scheme.

Answer (score 0):

(wince) this sounds like "security through obscurity", and a lot of unnecessary work.

Just set up an ssh tunnel and proxy your web traffic through that.

See http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/use-ssh-create-http-proxy

Comment: Necessity isn't the point, this is primarily an academic exercise with a (limited) practical application. I am aware that there are other options, but am taking the opportunity of having worked on this to improve myself. Do you know what I could do?